# How to fix "(HelloWorldWebPart) has a dependency on "@microsoft/sp-http" that is not declared in the manifest"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm trying to make an API call to a list in a sharepoint-react project using `SPHttpClient`. I'm importing it in the .tsx-file, because it gave the error in the .ts-file, but I get the same error.

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

Full error message:

```
Failed to load component "2176804e-8fe8-47bc-b39d-2a768528676e" (HelloWorldWebPart). Original error: The entry point for component "2176804e-8fe8-47bc-b39d-2a768528676e" (HelloWorldWebPart) has a dependency on "@microsoft/sp-http" that is not declared in the manifest.
```

The code that seems to be causing the issue, I can tell because the error doesn't appear when I comment out this function.

```
export interface SpListItem {
  Titel: string,
  ItemId: number,
}

export interface SpList {
  value: SpListItem[];
}

private _getListData(): Promise<SpList> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(
      this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Reservation')/Items",
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

EDIT: An error in the code after making the changes, I get a red squiggly line under `SPHttpClient.configurations.v1` saying:

```
Argument of type 'import("[PATH-TO-PROJECT]/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/dist/index-internal").SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("[PATH-TO-PROJECT]/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-component-base/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/dist/index-internal").SPHttpClientConfiguration'.
  Property 'flags' is protected but type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not a class derived from 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'.
```

Comment: Try doing a `gulp clean` to see if that fixes the problem. If not, could you edit your question an include the code for the web part and the React component. That will help people try and diagnose the issue.

Comment: @RobWindsor Sadly it didn't help, I did add some code like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I built a sample web part that uses `SpHttpClient` in the React component to get data from SharePoint. Hopefully you can take this, along with the information in the resources I've linked, and use it to get your web part working.

The first thing I noticed in the code you included in your question was the members of the `SpListItem` interface. These need to match the properties of the JSON that will be returned by SharePoint when you make a REST API request. You made a typo in the name of the first member, it should be `Title` instead of `Titel`. For the second member, I assume you want the Id of the item. If that's the case then the member should be `Id` instead of `ItemId`.

The second thing I noticed was the use of `this.context` in the `_getListData()` method. The `context` member of the React component is not the same as the `context` member of the web part. It does not have members like `spHttpClient` or `pageContext`. To get access to `spHttpClient` an `pageContext` you need to pass the value of the `context` member of the web part (which is of type `WebPartContext`) to the React component. You do this through the React component's properties. These are defined by the `ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps` in the sample below. You can then access the `WebPartContext` passed from the web part using `this.props.context` in the React component.

Please note that in the sample below, the code for `ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps` and `ISpHttpDependencyIssueState` would normally be put in sperate files. I've just included it all with the React component to make things easier to read.

Please also note that I used the most recent version of the SharePoint Framework (v1.14) for my sample. The project files generated by this version of the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generator are different from previous versions (for example, they add support for theming). So you may see code in my sample that is different than what you see if your project.

Here are the links to the resources I mentioned. They provide additional information on the use of React in SharePoint Framework web parts and the use of the `SpHttpClient` to interact with SharePoint data.

I hope all of this helps.

[How to get started with React for Building Advanced SPFx solutions](https://laurakokkarinen.com/how-to-get-started-with-react-for-building-advanced-spfx-solutions/)

[YouTube: Using React in SharePoint Framework Projects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjSrFYFQXtc)

[Microsoft Learn: Work with SharePoint Content using the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-spcontent?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698)

**Code for the React component**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './SpHttpDependencyIssue.module.scss';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps {
  description: string;
  isDarkTheme: boolean;
  environmentMessage: string;
  hasTeamsContext: boolean;
  userDisplayName: string;
  context: WebPartContext;
}

export interface SpListItem {
  Title: string;
  Id: number;
}

export interface SpList {
  value: SpListItem[];
}

export interface ISpHttpDependencyIssueState {
  productData: SpListItem[];
}

export default class SpHttpDependencyIssue extends React.Component<ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps, ISpHttpDependencyIssueState> {
  private _getListData(): Promise<SpList> {
    return this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(
      this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Products')/Items",
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  public constructor(props: ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { productData: [] };
  }

  public async componentDidMount() {
    var productData = await this._getListData();
    this.setState({ productData: productData.value });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps> {
    const {
      description,
      isDarkTheme,
      environmentMessage,
      hasTeamsContext,
      userDisplayName
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <section className={`${styles.spHttpDependencyIssue} ${hasTeamsContext ? styles.teams : ''}`}>
        <div className={styles.welcome}>
          <img alt="" src={isDarkTheme ? require('../assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('../assets/welcome-light.png')} className={styles.welcomeImage} />
          <h2>Well done, {escape(userDisplayName)}!</h2>
          <div>{environmentMessage}</div>
          <div>Web part property value: <strong>{escape(description)}</strong></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Welcome to SharePoint Framework!</h3>
          <p>
            The SharePoint Framework (SPFx) is a extensibility model for Microsoft Viva, Microsoft Teams and SharePoint. It's the easiest way to extend Microsoft 365 with automatic Single Sign On, automatic hosting and industry standard tooling.
          </p>
          <h4>Products:</h4>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.productData.map((productItem) => {
                return <li>{productItem.Title}</li>;
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

**Code for the render method of the web part**:

```
public render(): void {
  const element: React.ReactElement<ISpHttpDependencyIssueProps> = React.createElement(
    SpHttpDependencyIssue,
    {
      description: this.properties.description,
      isDarkTheme: this._isDarkTheme,
      environmentMessage: this._environmentMessage,
      hasTeamsContext: !!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams,
      userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
      context: this.context
    }
  );

  ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Comment: I used your solution to check what would happen, but I get a red squiggly line under the configuration parameter of the `.get()` function. I edited the question with the error-message. Seen this before?